# JSTL передача параметра в value из input

Tags: java, jstl

Доброго времени! Подскажите как передать значение из input в value?

```
<c:url var="findAction" value="/userfind/${ПАРАМЕТР ИЗ INPUT}"/>
```

Вот кусок кода:

```
    <c:url var="findAction" value="/userfind/${findUser}"/>
<form:form action="${findAction}" commandName="user">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <c:if test="${empty user.userName}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Find User"/>"/>
                </c:if>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="fi" name="findUser" type="text" size="40"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не отвечу на твой вопрос, но посоветую: "Не проще ли будет, передавать нужный параметр через POST и уже после обрабатывать его?"

т.е.:

```
<form:form action="/finduser" commandName="user" method = "post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="fi" name="findUser" type="text" size="40"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <c:if test="${empty user.userName}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Find User"/>"/>
                </c:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Да и на сколько я понимаю, когда тебе выводится .jsp страничка она уже интерпретирована, соответственно все переменные заранее (должны быть) определены.
По мне разумнее передавать параметр через пост, а у же внутри контроллера делать запрос.

Comment: Спасибо! Ты был прав! Сделал так, в контроллере так: @RequestMapping(value="/userfind", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String searchUser(@RequestParam("findUser") String userName, Model model) { ...} Выручил!!!